# Learning Bootstrap, how to make a column stack correctly after other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement bootstrap on my actual html, there's only 2 parts where it really needs it so it's easy and i don't need to re-make all the code.

So, that's basically what i want, and that's what i'm having on my 1080p screen.

[image: 1080p no problems]

But when i make it a little smaller

[image: smaller with some problems]

The title goes like that:

```
Liga
Juizforana
```

and not:

```
Liga Juizforana
```

(i forgot the term when text does this, sorry for my noobness)

and the trophy get a little lost

when the screen get even smaller
[image: even smaller screen problems]

the trophy don't get under the black transparent div with the description

and when it's mobile screen:
[image: big problem]

the trophy passes through everything, it's supposed to go under the black div, and push the div(with the bg) down, to fit in there, and not go above everything(the red div).

html:

```
<div class='conteudo col-md-offset-1'>

        <div class='inicio'>
        <a id='inicio'></a>
            <div class='topo'>
                <div class='subir col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1'>
                <div>
                <p class='titulo'>Liga Juizforana</p>

                <hr size='1' align='left'>

                <p class='subtit'>A Liga Juizforana tem o intuito de trazer campeonatos diversos para a cidade focando em League of Legends. A intenção do campeonato é a diversão de todos, tendo campeonatos sempre que possível para todos se interagirem, conhecerem e entrarem no cenário competitivo da cidade.</p>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class='grandelogo col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-7'>
                    <img src='imagens/LigaJFLogo.png' border='0px' alt='LigaJFLogo' title='LigaJFLogo'>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='textos'>
                <p id='intro'>A Liga Juizforana tem o intuito de trazer campeonatos diversos para a área da cidade começando por League of Legends. A intenção do campeonato é o foco na diversão de todos, tendo campeonatos sempre que possível para todos entrarem no cenário competitivo da cidade.<br><br>

                Dessa vez é a terceira edição :D. Inicialmente o campeonato vai ser focado em ter 16 times no total, e conseguimos recompensa da própria Riot! Inicialmente o campeonato será online mas caso cresçamos o campeonato pode ter etapas offline, e caso você queira ajudar com isso, pode mandar uma mensagem pelo próprio sistema de contato pelo site.</p>

                <div class='logoLol'>
                    <img src='imagens/lolLogo.png' border='0px' alt='lolLogo' title='lolLogo'>
                </div>
.
.
.
```

i like to put all those classes to understand what's everything and try to avoid some problems, who knows if i use something with the same name etc and bugs everything.
css:

```
.conteudo {
    }

.conteudo .topo {
    height: 952px;
    background-image: url("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/upload/art/wp_alistar_vs_olaf_1920x1080.jpg");
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.topo .titulo {
    max-width: 85%;
    font-size: 74px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topo hr {
}

.subir{
    padding-top: 250px;

}

.topo .subtit {
    margin-left: 80px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
}


.subir div {    
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}


.grandelogo {
    margin-top: -34%;
}
```

i'm so noob with responsiveness and i'm trying to learn, but nothing works, please, help me D:, i didn't wanted to ask this but i tried a lot and i wanted to have tips to that, something that i could do. I know it's a big question, but, basically it's simple to you who knows, i just put lots of screens to you guys understand easily the problem

Comment: What do you think `col-lg-6` means? Hint: lg = large

Comment: I do know that ¬¬'
I used large because i want large screens to be like the first image i sent, and in md, sm and xs screens i wanted it to stack under the other div. Since i just want to make it stacks under large screens, i used the lg one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to tweak your HTML structure a bit to use a few of the default bootstrap classes.

Basically you're going to want to structure your code using a combination of **rows** and **columns**.

In your example you have two large content blocks (the transparent black block and the trophy image).

These should be contained in a single row but within two separate columns. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Liga Juizforana Block</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Trophy Block</div>
</div>
```

Any content which exists along with those two blocks should be contained in further `<div class="row">` blocks.

I'd perhaps even tweak your full markup so the entire page was wrapped in a single row with the left side nav being in one column and the main page content being in another column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        Left-Side Nav
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        <div class="row large-background">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Liga Juizforana Block</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Trophy Block</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'd apply our background to the inner row (or the parent column class) and style it so it looks right on mobile. Remember it's almost always easier to start with the mobile markup first and then style it to be desktop after.

Make sure to check the Bootstrap docs for the grid (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more information as they provide lots of great examples with markup.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't realized i was forgetting the rows! D: Thaaank you soo much, and i'll try this NOW! Thaaaanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap it's important to focus on **mobile first**.
If you want a column to use full width on small screens, half width on larger screens and 1/4 width on the largest screens, you have to specify it:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
```

When it comes to the problem with your text wrapping, you can use media queries to make the text smaller:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .titulo {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .titulo {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, with that i'm saying, "hey, in mobiles, i want it to be 100% the width of the screen, in md i want it to be half of the screen!", something like that? i thought this was just to make columns stack and we had to set the number according with the content inside something we want.

Comment: Yeah, if you have 4 columns with `col-sm-12 col-lg-6` within one row, it will stack for each and every column on small screens and for every second on large screens.

Comment: Btw, it's not relative to the screen, but rather the size of the parent.

Comment: I'm getting now, thanks! But i'm still with the problem that the trophy doesn't push the div that has that background image, i found that the height of it was fixed, than i changed to min-height and it worked, until i set the columns to smaller devices :/